Uncheck a checkbox prompt when another checkbox prompt is unchecked
In a Cognos report i have 2 checkbox prompts named :

ChoicesIndicator1_VALUE
ChoicesIndicator1_VALUE_b1

When the first one is clicked / unchecked, the second one has to also be unchecked.
I can't do this with Cognos so i'm using javascript.
The idea is as follows :

    <script>   
    
    var form = getFormWarpRequest();
    var myList  = form._oLstChoicesIndicator1_VALUE 
    var myListb1  = form._oLstChoicesIndicator1_VALUE_b1 
    
    myList.onclick = function() {myFunction()};
    
    function myFunction()
    {
              if(myList.checked == true)
              {   
                 myList.checked = false;  
              }
    }
    
    </script>    


The if is working but not the "myList.checked = false"; (an alert("hello"); is working).
So i guess there's something wrong.
Note : i'd rather use the prompt name if possible. If the prompt ID is needed, can it be attached to the prompt with JS code ?
Anybody knows how to correct this?
Update 07/05/2024 :
Thanks for those 2 solutions.
I've tried both solutions but it's not working.
The first solution, what i need is :
<script>   

var form = getFormWarpRequest();
var myList  = form._oLstChoicesIndicator1_VALUE;
var myListb1  = form._oLstChoicesIndicator1_VALUE_b1;

myList.onclick = function() {myListOnclick()};

function myListOnclick() { 
  myListb1.checked = false;
}

</script> 

The Indicator1_VALUE check box is checked by default and is impossible to uncheck. If i replace "myListb1.checked = false;" by "alert("hello");", the pop up "hello" shows up and the Indicator1_VALUE check box remains checked when it's clicked. I don't get it :(
Here is the html code generated by Cognos for the first checkbox :
   <input name="pOpt_N00000183677D8300x000001835420DB38_NS_" id="N00000183677D8300x000001835420DBE8_NS_" type="checkbox" role="checkbox" value="EVOL" dv="% evol" class="dijitCheckBoxInput" onclick="return PRMTUtils.F_OnChange(event, this);" onkeypress="return PRMTUtils.F_OnChange(event, this);" onfocus="return PRMTUtils.f_CheckboxOnFocus(this);" onblur="return PRMTUtils.f_CheckboxOnBlur(this);" tabindex="0" aria-checked="true">

and the seconde checkbox :
<input name="pOpt_N00000183677D8300x000001835420E168_NS_" id="N00000183677D8300x000001835420E1C0_NS_" type="checkbox" role="checkbox" value="YES" dv="Block 1" class="dijitCheckBoxInput" onclick="return PRMTUtils.F_OnChange(event, this);" onkeypress="return PRMTUtils.F_OnChange(event, this);" onfocus="return PRMTUtils.f_CheckboxOnFocus(this);" onblur="return PRMTUtils.f_CheckboxOnBlur(this);" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false">

Do you have any idea ?
Thanks!
Regards, Antoine

Isn't that what radio buttons were designed for?

I think the problem is that when you are checking that checkbox, you are at the same time unchecking it. I modified that a bit. Now it should work.


var form = getFormWarpRequest();
var myList  = form._oLstChoicesIndicator1_VALUE;
var myListb1  = form._oLstChoicesIndicator1_VALUE_b1;

myList.onclick = function() {myListOnclick()};
myListb1.onclick = function() {myListb1Onclick()};

function myListOnclick() { 
  myListb1.checked = false;
}

function myListb1Onclick() {
  myList.checked = false;  
}



Also, you have no need to check if your checkbox are checked becouse those are already onclick functions.

Hello, i've updated my first message with my answer...any one has a clue ? Thanks a lot. Regards, Antoine

You are saying "When the first one is clicked / unchecked, the second one has to also be unchecked." So, here is an event listener for the input event (don't use the click event in a situation like this -- the input event will happen when a value of an input has changed). If the value changes (there is input) on the _oLstChoicesIndicator1_VALUE input, the checked value of _oLstChoicesIndicator1_VALUE_b1 will be false.


//var form = getFormWarpRequest();
var form = document.forms.form01;

form.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if (e.target.name == '_oLstChoicesIndicator1_VALUE') {
    e.target.form._oLstChoicesIndicator1_VALUE_b1.checked = false;
  }
});
<form name="form01">
  <label>No. 1: <input type="checkbox" name="_oLstChoicesIndicator1_VALUE"></label>
  <label>No. 2: <input type="checkbox" name="_oLstChoicesIndicator1_VALUE_b1"></label>
</form>



